# Permission Error when using vim-geeknote

Tags: macvim

I was trying to use [vim-geeknote](https://github.com/neilagabriel/vim-geeknote) in MacVim ([Kaoriya Edition](https://github.com/splhack/macvim-kaoriya), MacVim modified for Japanese environment).

I followed [the official way](http://www.geeknote.me/install/) of installing geeknote and it works in terminal (with `sudo`).

I used NeoBundle to install `vim-geeknote`, writing the following code in `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Geeknote
NeoBundle 'sudo.vim'
NeoBundle 'neilagabriel/vim-geeknote'
noremap <F8> :Geeknote<cr>
let g:GeeknoteMaxExplorerWidth=60
```

However, when I execute `:Geeknote` in MacVim, I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Tak/.vim/bundle/vim-geeknote/plugin/vim_geeknote.py", line 4, in <module>
    from explorer import Explorer
  File "/Users/Tak/.vim/bundle/vim-geeknote/plugin/explorer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from view   import *
  File "/Users/Tak/.vim/bundle/vim-geeknote/plugin/view.py", line 4, in <module>
    from enml  import *
  File "/Users/Tak/.vim/bundle/vim-geeknote/plugin/enml.py", line 5, in <module>
    from geeknote.out    import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/geeknote-0.2a-py2.7.egg/geeknote/out.py", line 11, in <
module>
    from editor import Editor
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/geeknote-0.2a-py2.7.egg/geeknote/editor.py", line 16, i
n <module>
    from log import logging
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/geeknote-0.2a-py2.7.egg/geeknote/log.py", line 11, in <
module>
    logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, filename=config.ERROR_LOG)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.p
y", line 1545, in basicConfig
    hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.p
y", line 911, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.p
y", line 941, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Tak/.geeknote/error.log'
```

Since the permission is denied, I tried:

- `sudo chmod a+rw /Library/Python/2.7/`
- `sudo chmod a+rw /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`

but they don't work and I keep getting the same error.
Is there any way to execute commands with `sudo`? Or are there any better way for this issue?

Comment: The permission error seems to be on the file `/Users/Tak/.geeknote/error.log` have you tried changing the permissions for this file?

Comment: I'm glad it solved the problem :-) Now as I think that the question isn't related to Vim or it's usage but to the permissions properties of your system I'll vote to close the question.